# Getting WordPress Flexslider Item Number

Tags: custom-post-types

I add flexslider to my theme home page via this code.how can I get number of per item?

**as 1 2 3 4 ......**

```
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'try', 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    ?>

      <li class="featured-game">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured'); ?>
        <div class="caption">
            <a href="#" class="game-title"><?php the_title();?></a>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a href="#" class="playnow">Play Now</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    <?php
        endwhile;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$item_nr = $query->current_post;
```

to give you the position within the loop (starts from `0`).

If you need the first item to start with `1`, you can use:

```
$item_nr = $query->current_post;
$item_nr++;
```

Total number of posts found:

```
$items_found = $query->found_posts;
```

Comment: thanks. I found css value as text-indent: -9999px; for hiding.